# Making the decomposition of a polyhedron unique

Tags: geometry, linear-programming, polyhedra, polytopes

It is well known that a convex polyhedron $D$ can be written as the Minkowski sum of a polytope $P$ and a positive cone $C$. It is equally well-known that the $C$ in the decomposition is unique ; in fact, $C$ is necessarily the so-called characteristic cone of $D$ :

$$
C=\bigg\lbrace c \ \bigg| \ \forall x\in D, x+c\in D \bigg\rbrace
$$

All the presentations I've seen note that $P$ is obviously nonunique (since we may add an arbitrary finite number of elements of $C$ to $P$ and take the convex hull, and still get a polytope making the decomposition true) but none wonder if one can make it unique by adding an extra constraint.

A natural (to me) definition is as follows : let

$$
M=\bigg\lbrace x\in D \bigg| \forall x'\in D, \ x+C \subseteq x'+C \Rightarrow x'=x \bigg\rbrace 
$$

and let $\Pi$ be the convex hull of $M$.

**Question.** Is $\Pi$ a polytope, and does the decomposition $D=\Pi+C$ hold ?

If the answer to both those questions is yes, then it makes sense to consider $D=\Pi+C$ as the "canonical" decomposition.

My thoughts :

1. When $D$ is an "obelisk" (a pyramid with square base sitting on top of an infinite parelliped), then $M$ is the frontier of the pyramid minus the interior of the base, so that $M$ is not convex or closed in this case.
2. If we start with an arbitrary decomposition $D=P+C$ where $P$ is the convex hull of a finite number of points $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_m$, it would seem that $\Pi$ is the convex hull of the $p_i$'s that are contained in $M$, but I have been unable to prove this so far.

Here are the (standard) definitions I use : a polyhedron is an intersection of a finite number of half-spaces (i.e. sets of the form $\lbrace x | \phi(x)\geq c\rbrace$ where $\phi$ is a linear form and $c$ is a constant), a polytope is the convex hull of a finite set of points, and  a positive cone is the "positive hull" (i.e. the sets of all linear combinations with nonnegative coefficients) of a finite set of vectors.

Comment: Can you give a good reference for the first result ($D=P+C$) ? Thank you !

Comment: @JeanMarie Not sure what you consider a "good" reference, but if you're looking for an online resource, look at theorem 4.18 of https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis6100/convex45.pdf). There are also well-known books on the subject, such as Günter Ziegler's "Lectures on Polytopes"

Comment: Thank you for the online reference. Yes, I know the excellent book by Ziegler.